# Error while Packaging and Distributing Electron Desktop Apps in Windows

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I have created a sample Electron App and i need to create a .exe file from it. I managed to build the app without errors but when i start the app an error appears.I cant figure out why im getting this.How to resolve this?.

The Error im getting
[image]

My package.json file

```
{
  "name": "wordsum",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron main.js",
    "package-mac": "electron-packager . --overwrite --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --icon=App/assets/WSlogo.icns --prune=true --out=release-builds",
    "build": "electron-packager . --overwrite --asar=true --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --icon=App/assets/WSlogo.ico --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=DevX --version-string.FileDescription=DevX --version-string.ProductName=\"WordSum\"",
    "package-linux": "electron-packager . --overwrite --platform=linux --arch=x64 --icon=App/assets/WSlogo.png --prune=true --out=release-builds"
  },
  "author": "Thaaraka Romesh",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.6.2",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^1.4.15",
    "electron-packager": "^8.5.1"
  }
}
```

The Repo of the project [Electron project](https://github.com/TRomesh/WordSum)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out whats wrong. In my package.json file its mentioned as **"main": "index.js"** but im my app the actual main file is called main.js.